# SQL Join Related Query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

Hi i have one doubt about many to many relationship. I have three table Employee, Department and EDJoin table. Here EDJoin table contains both Employee and Department table's id and i want to join both these table to get both table data. Using EDJoin table how i will established join between these two table i.e Employee and Department. Here is column details for both Employee and Department table below. 
Employee: 
  empId 
  firstName 
  middleName 
  lastName 
  age

Department: 
  departmentId 
  departmentName

EDJoin: 
  empId 
  departmentId

Please tell me the query for these tale. How to write query for these three tables so that i can fetch data from both Employee and Department table.

Thanks & Regards 
Sailendra Narayan Jena

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
select *
from Employee a
inner join EDJoin b on a.empIDd = b.empId
inner join Department c on b.departmentId = c.departmentId
```

Noel

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Employee as a
INNER JOIN EdJoin as b ON a.Id = b.empId
INNER JOIN Deparment as c ON b.deptId = c.id;
```

if you want to display specific column replace (*)
ex.

```
SELECT firstName,MiddleName,LastName,age,DeparmentName 
FROM Employee as a
INNER JOIN EdJoin as b ON a.Id = b.empId
INNER JOIN Department as c ON b.deptId = c.id;
```